# How to update a specific location within a CSV File?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am currently working on assignment in which we are provided a skeleton code for a library system. The user is able to enter various commands from a menu which allows them to query or check-in/out items.

The items are stored within two CSV files (library_collections["movies"], library_collections["books"] and have already been loaded by the skeleton code.I have already written code for the query functionality, however, I am having trouble with the Check-in/out function.

After the user enters their command at the menu, they are prompted to enter an Item ID, which is then supposed to match up to an ID within the CSV file.

Here is my code for the check in.

```
 def cib(id , library_collections):
     for i in library_collections["books"]:
         if id == i["ID"]:
             i["Available"]=i["Available"]+1
             return 'Item has successfully Been Checked In'
         elif id != i['ID']:
             return 'Please restart the program and enter a valid ID'
```

The output for the Check in
`output: None`

Here is my code for the check out.

```
def cob(id, library_collections):
    for i in library_collections["books"]:
        if id == i["ID"]:
            if i["Available"] > 0:
                i["Available"] = i["Available"] - 1
                return('Item Successfully Checked-out')
            elif i["Available"] == 0:
                print('There are no more available copies')
        elif id != i["ID"]:
            return'Please restart the program and enter a valid ID'
```

The output for the Check out 
`output: 'Please restart the program and enter a valid ID'`

Whenever I enter an ID that I know is in the CSV file, both functions give me the same outputs as written above. Therefore, both have no effect on the CSV file.

Comment: Your first function doesn't work because it `return`s on the first iteration that doesn't match and doesn't look further. Your second function has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your boot isn't first in list you fall to elif and return error message

This might work:

```
def cib(id , library_collections):
     for i in library_collections["books"]:
         if id == i["ID"]:
             i["Available"]=i["Available"]+1
             return 'Item has successfully Been Checked In'
     return 'Please restart the program and enter a valid ID'
```

So you first loop through all books and if the book isn't found you'll return error message.

Same thing in cob method

Looping through list of dicts isn't effective way to do this. If I was coding something like that and I couldn't use proper databases for some reason I'd parse the CSV to dict. Datamodel might be something like this:

```
{ 1: {"available": 10, "name": "Hamlet", "author": "W. Shakespeare", "year": 1609},
  123: {"available": 0, "name": "Война и мир", "author": "L. Tolstoi", "year": 1869},
}
```

Where 1 and 123 are ids. You can user strings as an id as well. Then you simple do your method like

```
def cib(id, library_collection): 
   try:
       library_collection[id]["available"] += 1
       return 'Item has successfully Been Checked In'
   except:
        return 'Please restart the program and enter a valid ID'
```

Or

```
def cib(id, library_collection): 
    if id in library_collection:
       library_collection[id]["available"] += 1
       return 'Item has successfully Been Checked In'
    else:
        return 'Please restart the program and enter a valid ID'
```

Avoid for-loops is always good idea.